# What are the canonical definitions of common terms used in the context of satipaṭṭhāna from the Tripitaka or related literature

Tags: reference-request, sati, sampajana, atappa

What are the canonical definitions of the following words (sati, sampajañña, appamada, atappa, manasikara, satipaṭṭhāna) from the Tipitaka, commentaries, sub commentaries, including primary, secondary or tertiary source with citations:

[image: Samprajaña, apramāda and atappa]

Image source: [Sati (Buddhism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(Buddhism))

Answer (score 1):

Mindfulness is not "awareness". Mindfulness is remembering, as follows:

> *When one has heard the Dhamma from such bhikkhus one dwells withdrawn
>   by way of two kinds of withdrawal—withdrawal of body and withdrawal of
>   mind. Dwelling thus withdrawn, one **recollects (anussarati)** that Dhamma and
>   thinks it over. Whenever, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu dwelling thus withdrawn
>   recollects that Dhamma and thinks it over, on that occasion the
>   enlightenment factor of **mindfulness (sati)** is aroused by the bhikkhu; on thatoccasion the bhikkhu develops the enlightenment factor of mindfulness;
>   on that occasion the enlightenment factor of mindfulness comes to
>   fulfilment by development in the bhikkhu.*
>
> *https://suttacentral.net/sn46.3/en/bodhi*
>
> ---
>
> *One is mindful to abandon wrong view & to **enter (upasampajja) & remain (viharati)** in right
>   view: This is one's right **mindfulness (sati)**.*
>
> *https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html*
>
> ---
>
> *"What is sammasati? Sati means to **bear in mind or bring to mind**. Sati
>   is the state of **recollecting**, the state of **remembering**, the state of
>   **non-fading**, the state of **non-forgetting**. Sati means the sati that is a
>   Spiritual Faculty, the sati that is a Spiritual Power, Sammasati, the
>   Sati that is an Enlightenment Factor, that which is a Path Factor and
>   that which is related to the Path. This is what is called sammasati."
>   Vbh.105, 286*

Sampajanna (saṃ + pajāna) is active supervisory wisdom. It means ready wisdom, situational wisdom, to thoroughly understand. Sampajanna is not Western/Jewish '*bare zombie awareness*'. When SN 47.35 briefly defines ‘sampajana’, it uses the word “vidita” (pp. of vindati), which means “to understand” or “understood”, as Bhikkhu Bodhi properly translated as “understood”, as follows:

> *And how, bhikkhus, does a bhikkhu exercise clear comprehension? Here,
>   bhikkhus, for a bhikkhu feelings are understood as they arise,
>   understood as they remain present, understood as they pass away.
>   Thoughts are understood as they arise, understood as they remain
>   present, understood as they pass away. Perceptions are understood as
>   they arise, understood as they remain present, understood as they pass
>   away. It is in this way, bhikkhus, that a bhikkhu exercises clear
>   comprehension.*
>
> ---
>
> *Because I understand the diversity of faculties as it applies to this person.*
>
> *Indriyavemattatā hi me, udāyi, imasmiṃ puggale viditā.*
>
> *MN 66*
>
> ---
>
> *However, I have recognized individual differences.*
>
> *Api ca mayā puggalavemattatā viditā”ti.*
>
> *SN 12.17*

Manasikara is manas or thought. Thus it is attention directed by thought or intention (rather than mere or pure consciousness/*vinnana*). For example:

> *Hearing the good Dhamma, becoming full, fills up faith. Faith, becoming full, fills up careful attention. Careful **attention**, becoming full, fills up mindfulness and clear comprehension. AN 10.61*

Satipaṭṭhāna, according to Bhikkhu Sujato, means establishing of mindfulness.

> *The function of satipaṭṭhāna as support for jhāna is suggested in a
>   very common Sutta idiom, whose significance tends to be obscured in
>   translation. The term satipaṭṭhāna (establishing of mindfulness)
>   resolves into sati and upaṭṭhāna. The alternative resolution into sati
>   and paṭṭhāna, though favoured by the commentaries, is spurious. The
>   difference between the two is that while upaṭṭhāna expresses the
>   subjective act of establishing or setting up mindfulness, paṭṭhāna
>   would refer to the ‘foundations’ of mindfulness, the objective domains
>   on which mindfulness is established. The basic meaning of upaṭṭhāna is
>   to ‘stand near’, and it is commonly used to mean ‘serve’, ‘approach’,
>   even ‘worship’. Taranatha Tarkavacaspati’s Sanskrit dictionary
>   gives the meaning of ‘causing to remember’...,
>   which would be identical with sati, but as this does not seem to be
>   attested in any early text it is probably under Buddhist influence. We
>   have already remarked that the closest parallel in the Upaniṣads is
>   the term upāsana. [Page 185](http://santifm.org/santipada/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/A_History_of_Mindfulness_Bhikkhu_Sujato.pdf)*